# Php Medoo select query

Tags: php, mysql, medoo

I need help with Medoo SQL query to select and display data of both columns on the below table but whenever I run my query only 1 row is returned is instead two, here's my query:

```
$database->select("chat_messages", "*", 
    [ "AND" => ["to_user_id" => 13, "from_user_id" => 14], "ORDER" => ["msg_time" => "DESC"] ]);
```

Is there something that I am missing to make the query display data for both `from_user_id` and `to_user_id` columns?

| id | from_user_id | to_user_id | message |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 13 | 14 | Hello |
| 2 | 14 | 13 | Morning |

The name of the table is `chat_messages`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `OR` instead of `AND`

Here is your updated query

```
$database->select("chat_messages", "*", 
[ "OR" => ["to_user_id" => 13, "from_user_id" => 14], "ORDER" => ["msg_time" => "DESC"]
```